# Size of characters in input sequence for Huffman encoding?

Tags: huffman-code

In Huffman compression we eliminate redundancy in a sequence of symbols due to usage variable length codes for symbols with different frequencies.

The question is **how to define the size** (in bits) **of** **input** symbols, is it 7,8,9,121? How to define it?

Comment: The length of the code for each symbol in bits is determined using the Huffman algorithm on the set of symbol frequencies. Look up the Huffman algorithm.

Comment: No, Huffman algoritthm works with INPUT fixed-sized-symbo input-data-items...Yes, it's OUTPUT size is determinited by algorithm. But no INPUT. From the description of algorithm from Lecture Notes or from wiki or from papers you will observe that examples usually look in input sequence is 8BIT Asciii symbols.

Comment: Huffman encoding works for any set of symbols. The set that is chosen depends on the application. The set of 256 possible values of an 8-bit byte is used for educational examples because it's easy to work with.

Comment: I have a file which is a text file with UTF8 text which is a sequence of bytes(i.e. sequence of bits), I can select size of symbol arbitarily - when I launched this algorithm(own draft implementation) I received different compression ratio depend on what size of symbol I selected. The question is "how to define the size (in bits) of input symbols" for input *bitstream*? The goal of this post to receive answer or experience or reference to somewhere how to define this.

Comment: Are you implementing a standard compression format, or making one up? If you're making up your own compression format based on Huffman codes, part of the design process is to define how many symbols there are and what they mean. Your symbol set doesn't even have to be sized to fit neatly in a certain number of bits. For example, if you look at the deflate specification, you'll find that in one place it uses an alphabet of 285 symbols.

Answer (score 0):

The Huffman algorithm does not care how you choose to represent your symbols. All it cares about is how many symbols there are and what the frequency of each symbol is. It just takes a list of frequencies and produces a list of bit lengths. Your symbols can be represented as bytes, two-byte integers, Unicode characters, country flags, whatever.